# Try to set Low Search to match one Category and any from Group of Categories

Tags: categories, low-search

I have two category groups. One is for *Towns* and the other is for *Designations*. Some *Designations* are state-related, some are national-related. So I've combined the categories that are state and the categories that are national into the value in checkboxes. I've put all *Towns* in a select.  The *Designations* categories are in checkboxes and look like this:

`<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="category[]"  value="2336|2332|2335" selected><label>National Register</label>
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="category[]"  value="2334|2337" selected><label>State Register</label>`

and the *Town* categories look like this:

`<select name="category[]" id="ctm_city">
<option value="">-- Select option --</option>

<option value="2158">Andover</option>
 <option value="2159">Ansonia</option>
 <option value="2160">Ashford</option>
 <option value="2161">Avon</option>
</select>`

I'd like if a *Town* category is selected that it is required but the designation categories can be any of the categories listed in its value. But I've only been able to get results from any of the combined categories (meaning the results match the town or match any of the Designations). Or if I use:

`<input type="hidden" name="require_all[]" value="category">`

then the results are only what matches everything...which is almost nothing. So being that both *Towns* and *Designations* are all categories (but 2 different category groups) how would I match selection from one *Town* category AND any category included in the selected *Designation* category checkbox?

As a test I've tried the query string:
`?category=2148&2334|2337`
and I get a disallowed query string error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since different parameters are always combined with `AND`, you can use a [category group](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#categories) setup, with 2 different groups.

So, for example, for designations, use `category:designations[]`, and for town, use `category:town`. You can omit the `[]` in the latter, as you're only selecting a single category there.

That will generate a query string like `category:designations=2334|2337&category:town=2148`.

Comment: That did it. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!